Crystal Report Fetching Multiple Data as Single Data
There is a problem I encountered in Crystal Report. In my table there are columns with car brands and models. Some brands have 1 model, some brands have more than one model. When bringing brands with more than one model, bring 1 record and write "there is more than one model" instead of the model name. How can I do that?
There is a problem I encountered in Crystal Report.
In my table there are columns with car brands and models. Some brands have 1 model, some brands have more than one model. When bringing brands with more than one model, bring 1 record and write "there is more than one model" instead of the model name. How can I do that?

Please provide a screen shot of this table with some real (or fake) data so we can better help you.
